# Upload video from Phone gap android app to youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, youtube-api

I am creating an app which will allow my users to upload their video on youtube. 
I have checked [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) to implement this using JAVASCRIPT but for this user has to login with their credentials and video will be uploaded to their account. But I don't want to ask my user their google credentials and also I want to upload all the videos on my own channel. 
To do the same I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392785/upload-video-to-youtube-from-android-app). The solution is working if I call upload script from my website but its not working if I use the same jquery in my APP.
Can anyone plz help me..

Comment: Thanks kenorb..I am now able to upload video..the issue was the file name that I was passing through APP was not correct..now it's working fine..

Comment: If it's working now, please post your own answer then, so it may be helpful for others.